# Passing git hub user.name through Unix variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, git, debugging, github

I am performing below operation

```
github_nam="Aviral Vishnoi"
git config --global user.name $github_nam
```

It is saving it as `user.name=Aviral`

I want it to store my full name as `user.name=Aviral Vishnoi`

I have tried single quote, double quotes and escape `\` character without success.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Set the var

```
github_nam="Aviral Vishnoi"
```

Then set the git config

```
git config --global user.name "$github_nam"
```

Note the quotes around `$github_nam`.

See the question "[When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)" for why the quotes matter.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me